# WinAPI MSG structure determine which key was pressed

Tags: winapi

Microsoft docs contain [MSG structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) page, which tells:

> wParam
>
> Type: WPARAM
>
> Additional information about the message. The exact meaning depends on
> the value of the message member.
>
> lParam
>
> Type: LPARAM
>
> Additional information about the message. The exact meaning depends on
> the value of the message member.

What is this "additional meaning"? They don't even link this page with others, which explain all of the possible additional meanings.

I had some very ugly code, which determined what registered hotkey was pressed, which looks like this:

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_NOREPEAT, VK_F2);
...

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY) != 0)
{
    switch (htonl(msg.lParam) >> 8)
    {
    case VK_ESCAPE:
        // handle escape
    case VK_F1:
        // handle F1
    // possibly handle some more buttons
    default:
        // handle stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is not the most elegant way to do this. Not elegant at all.

So, is there a better way (the best way) to determine which key was pressed from the MSG structure returned from GetMessage/PeekMessage?

EDIT: I understand that "meaning depends on the value of the message", give me the link to the page which maps "value of the message"->"meaning", please, instead of writing comments on how stupid am I. Much thanks.

Comment: As noted, the value depends on the `message` member. If the message is `WM_KEYDOWN` then they have one meaning. If the message is `WM_COMMAND` then it has another meaning.

Comment: There is no directory that maps values to 0 or more symbolic message constants. It's not clear why this would be helpful. You *know* that you are handling `WM_HOTKEY`, so you can look up the meaning of the arguments in the respective [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-hotkey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no unified message->meaning map page, but the document page of each individual window message. You need to know the message you want to use first, and then find the corresponding meaning in the document.

For example, the [`WM_HOTKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-hotkey) you are using, according to the document:

> wParam
>
> The identifier of the hot key that generated the message. If the
> message was generated by a system-defined hot key, this parameter will
> be one of the following values.
>
> lParam
>
> The low-order word specifies the keys that were to be pressed in
> combination with the key specified by the high-order word to generate
> the WM_HOTKEY message. This word can be one or more of the following
> values. The high-order word specifies the virtual key code of the hot
> key.

***is there a better way (the best way) to determine which key was pressed from the MSG structure returned from GetMessage/PeekMessage?***

Determine the pressed hot key through the `wParam` parameter (The identifier of the hot key). The second parameter of `RegisterHotKey` specifies the identifier of the hot key

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_NOREPEAT, VK_F2);
...

    switch (msg.wParam)
    {
    case 1:
        // handle VK_F2
    default:
        // handle stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for